# UIImagePickerController with Custom view Doesn't focus on touch on iOS5

Tags: ios, focus, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm initializing a pretty simple custom camera the following way :

```cpp
camview = [[CameraView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraView" bundle:nil];
camPicker.cameraOverlayView = camview.view;
camPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
camPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

But when trying to touch the camera to focus, it won't work.

Could you assist me with some tips as how to resolve this? I've tried googling and searching here on SO but found nothing useful .

Thanks!
Shai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code on an iPad 2 I was able to make it respond to focus touches by changing:

```
camPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

to:

```
camPicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

Comment: That makes sense, but i guess I would have to cover the controls if i'm using a custom view. Thanks anyways! :)